# Getting files uploaded correctly using Laravel

Tags: php, file-upload, laravel-4, eloquent

I am having some trouble with a photo upload system I'm working on in Laravel. So far, I have the file coming in and saving in public/images/profiles just fine, but I can't figure out how to insert it into the db with the right information. Currently I'm getting a "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::save() " error.

In my controller, I am currently trying to insert it by doing this:

```
public function updatePhotos($id)
{
    if(Input::hasFile('image'))
    //If file is being added 
    {
        $extension = Input::file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileName = str_random(9).'.'.$extension;

        $user = User::find($id);
        $user->profile->photo->type = 1;
        $user->profile->photo->filename = $fileName;
        $user->profile->photo->save();

        Input::file('image')->move('public/images/profiles/',$fileName);
    }
}
```

In the Photo model:

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Profile');
}
```

In the profile model, I have:

```
public function photo()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Photo','user_id','user_id');
}
```

Could anybody send me on the right course for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to save the user model, you have to create a new photo model, fill it with data and save it.

```
public function updatePhotos($id)
{
    $image = new Image();
    $image->user_id = Auth::id();
    $image->fill(Input::all());

    if (Input::hasFile('file')) {
        $file             = Input::file('file');
        $image->extension = $file->guessClientExtension();
        $image->size      = $file->getClientSize();
        $image->filename  = str_random(9) . '.' . $image->extension;
        $uploadSuccess    = $file->move('public/images/profiles/', $image->filename);

        $image->save();

        $user = User::find($id);
        $user->image = $image->id;
        $user-save();
        }
    }
}
```

- New image object created.
- Field `user_id` on image object is set to the current users ID.
- All `fillable` fields are filled with data from the form.
- If input has file, file is set to `$image->user_id = Auth::id();`
- Image extension, size and filename is set on image object.
- Image is moved (placed) in `public/images/profiles/` folder.
- Image object is saved.
- Get user object, assign `image` field with image ID and save user object.